# Limited attempts for login

Tags: php, security, authentication, block

I'm creating a login system and want to block the person trying to log in for a few minutes when the wrong username and password are given for lets say 4 times.

I know how to block it on IP but that would create a block for eg. an entire school, if I'm there.
Now I could use the username that the person is entering to block access but that leaves the possibility that the username entered does not exist in the database.

My question is:
How can I create that block for someone that enters a username that does not exist.
And what kind of database tables would i need for that.

Also i have looked for the possibility to use the session and cookies for it but that leaves a security issue of software that people can create to remove the sessions and cookies.

So if anyone could help me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: I would say, go for a solution that's 99% valid.  You're right, blocking by IP address is not a good idea as that could lock out large groups of users; plus if somebody wants to they can spoof their ip address.  Blocking by a username is effective only if somebody is trying to guess a password for a particular users; sessions/cookies can be deleted by end users easily.  I suggest going using a combination of several methods: lock username after N unsuccessfully login attempts, use sessions to whatever degree the user lets use and, possibly block IP address after a large number of attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to escape from the brute-force attacks, rather than a poor husband who forgot his username.

Implement a difficult CAPTCHA mechanism, so you could prevent most of the automated attacks. Simultaneously keep count of the attempts from a particular IP address and the interval between those successive attempts. If any attack manages to solve your CAPTCHA, still you can detect the abnormal activity in a couple of minutes and block access to that entire IP. It might put a whole organisation offline for a while, but at least you can help them out from experiencing a blackout because of a serious attack.

Sessions and cookies are not going to help because most of the brute-force systems clear and generate a new cookie for every request.

Comment: Thnks for the tip.
I will look into it.
Seems like a nice solution for this problem :)